# Out of memory Error when using scala to process some xml

Tags: java, xml, scala, lucene

I have broken wiki xml dump into many small parts of 1M and tried to clean it (after cleaning it with another program by somebody else)

I get an out of memory error which I don't know how to solve. Can anyone enlighten me?

I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.lucene.index.FreqProxTermsWriterPerField$FreqProxPostingsArray.<init>(FreqProxTermsWriterPerField.java:212)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.FreqProxTermsWriterPerField$FreqProxPostingsArray.newInstance(FreqProxTermsWriterPerField.java:235)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ParallelPostingsArray.grow(ParallelPostingsArray.java:48)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.TermsHashPerField$PostingsBytesStartArray.grow(TermsHashPerField.java:252)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRefHash.add(BytesRefHash.java:292)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.TermsHashPerField.add(TermsHashPerField.java:151)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain$PerField.invert(DefaultIndexingChain.java:645)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processField(DefaultIndexingChain.java:342)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processDocument(DefaultIndexingChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:241)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:454)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1541)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:1256)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:1237)
    at qa.main.ja.Indexing$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(SearchDocument.scala:234)
    at qa.main.ja.Indexing$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(SearchDocument.scala:224)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:750)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1202)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at qa.main.ja.Indexing$$anonfun$5.apply(SearchDocument.scala:224)
    at qa.main.ja.Indexing$$anonfun$5.apply(SearchDocument.scala:220)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
```

Where line 234 is as follows:

```
writer.addDocument(document)
```

It is adding some documents to Lucene

and where line 224 is as follows:

```
for (doc <- target_xml \\ "doc") yield {
```

It is the first line of a for loop for adding various elements as fields in the index.

Is it a code problem, setting problem or hardware problem?

**EDIT**

Hi, this is my for loop:

```
for (knowledgeFile <- knowledgeFiles) yield {
System.err.println(s"processing file: ${knowledgeFile}")
val target_xml=XML.loadString("    <file>"+cleanFile(knowledgeFile).mkString+"</file>")
for (doc <- target_xml \\ "doc") yield {
val id = (doc \ "@id").text
val title = (doc \ "@title").text
val text = doc.text
val document = new Document()
document.add(new StringField("id", id, Store.YES))
document.add(new TextField("text", new StringReader(title + text)))
writer.addDocument(document)
val xml_doc = <page><title>{ title }</title><text>{ text }</text></page>
id -> xml_doc
}
}).flatten.toArray`
```

The inner loop just loops thru every doc element. The outer loop loops thru every file. Is the nested for the source of the problem?

Below is the cleanFile function for reference:

```
def cleanFile(fileName:String):Array[String] = {
val tagRe = """<\/?doc.*?>""".r
val lines = Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines.toArray
val outLines = new Array[String](lines.length)
for ((line,lineNo) <- lines.zipWithIndex) yield {
if (tagRe.findFirstIn(line)!=None)
{
outLines(lineNo) = line
}
else
{
outLines(lineNo) = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml11(line)
}
}
outLines
}
```

---

Thanks again

Comment: Your exception occures when the JVM hasn't enougth memory. Can you show us your for loop ? (you may create too many objects etc in it)

Comment: 1M of XML file can go a very long way when unmarshalled into a DOM tree.

Comment: @laune especially if that is [some kind of zip bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I have added the codes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you would like to try increasing the heap size by having -xmx jvm argument?